# What's a clever way to find all possible combination of these two sets of items?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have two kinds of items

```
data Item1 = A | B | C
data Item2 = D | E | F
```

And two sets

```
set1 = [A,B,C]
set2 = [D,E,F]
```

I would like to find all unique ways of matching the items from two sets, the answer should be (in informal notation):

```
AD,BE,CF
AD,BF,CE
AE,BD,CF
AE,BF,CD
AF,BD,CE
AF,BE,CD
```

In other words, I would like some function that accomplish the following:

```
combine :: [Item1] -> [Item2] -> [[(Item1,Item2)]]
combine = undefined
```

Note each combination should be a tuple, and each row in the enumeration scheme above should be a list, for example:

```
[(A,D),(B,E),(C,F)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
import Data.List (sort, permutations)
combine as bs = zipWith zip (repeat as) (sort $ permutations bs)
```

Comment: FYI: `permutations` is part of the module `Data.List`.

Comment: The inclusion of the sort function is just to give the output in the order you described.  If you wrote your own `permutations` function then you wouldn't need it and you could make the `combine` function more general.

Comment: Generally, it's worth noting, all of the cleverness of this solution comes from `permutations`. In particular, recognizing that your matching problem is just a permutation of the input (to a subset of the output) and thus you want all `n!` permutations.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Precisely, I couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: `zipWith zip (repeat as) = map (zip as)`. Whenever you are combining `repeat` with `zipWith` you are essentially dealing with the `ZipList` Applicative, and the above equation follows from the Applicative law `liftA2 f (pure x) = fmap (f x)`.